# Pivot and grouping a DataFrame using another DataFrame with speed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot-table

I have two pandas `DataFrames` one with floats and one with corresponding dates. I am trying to 'pivot' the one containing floats `df1` using the dates in `df2` and sum along the rows if more than one date is occurring.

I have tried methods using `Pandas` and `NumPy` both together and separately, the results are correct, however the code can be very slow 1.2ms per loop over the `DataFrame`. Does anyone know how this same task can be achieved with more speed efficient code so that a 1,000,000+ row dataset could be passed through this?

I have got close with this code:

```py
        l = []
        for i in range(len(df1)):
            df_g = pd.DataFrame([df1.loc[i].values], columns=df2.loc[i].values)
            k = df_g.groupby(df_g.columns, axis=1).sum()
            l.append(k)

        df_concatenated = pd.concat(l)
```

Example Data:
`df1` floats

```
            0          1          2          3
0  170.590870  55.003686  18.500252  34.174595
1  170.590870  66.790190  12.377866  34.174595
2  140.922893  49.581099  18.500252  34.174595
3  170.590870  49.581099  18.500252  34.174595
```

`df2`

```
            0           1           2           3
0  30/06/2023  31/03/2023  25/10/2022  31/12/2023
1  30/06/2024  31/12/2022  25/10/2022  25/10/2022
2  31/12/2022  31/03/2023  25/10/2022  31/12/2023
3  31/12/2022  31/03/2023  25/10/2022  31/12/2023
```

Expected Output

```
   25/10/2022  31/12/2022  31/03/2023  30/06/2023  31/12/2023  30/06/2024
0   18.500252         NaN   55.003686  170.590870   34.174595         NaN
1   46.552461    66.79019         NaN         NaN         NaN   170.59087
2   18.500252  140.922893   49.581099         NaN   34.174595         NaN
3   18.500252   170.59087   49.581099         NaN   34.174595         NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `concat`

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['value', 'date'])
```

output:

```
value                                               date
0               1           2           3           0           1           2           3
0   170.590870  55.003686   18.500252   34.174595   30/06/2023  31/03/2023  25/10/2022  31/12/2023
1   170.590870  66.790190   12.377866   34.174595   30/06/2024  31/12/2022  25/10/2022  25/10/2022
2   140.922893  49.581099   18.500252   34.174595   31/12/2022  31/03/2023  25/10/2022  31/12/2023
3   170.590870  49.581099   18.500252   34.174595   31/12/2022  31/03/2023  25/10/2022  31/12/2023
```

`unpivot` above output and retry `pivot`

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['value', 'date']).stack().reset_index()
out = (df.pivot_table('value', index='level_0', columns='date', aggfunc='sum')
   .rename_axis('').sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)))
```

`out`

```
date    25/10/2022  31/12/2022  31/03/2023  30/06/2023  31/12/2023  30/06/2024
0       18.500252   NaN         55.003686   170.59087   34.174595   NaN
1       46.552461   66.790190   NaN         NaN         NaN         170.59087
2       18.500252   140.922893  49.581099   NaN         34.174595   NaN
3       18.500252   170.590870  49.581099   NaN         34.174595   NaN
```

if dtype of `df2` is datetime, don need `sort_index`